# Error using Logback Marker in FileAppender

Tags: java, logback, marker, fileappender

I have started exploring Logback option for our application. One of the requirement is to create a separate log file for log entries that have a specific "Marker".

Below is the logback.xml file that i am using and the error I am getting. The examples on the logback website shows the usage of SMTPAppender but I would like to use FileAppender instead. Is this possible? If not, what other option do i have?

```
<property name="USER_HOME" value="c:/temp" />

<appender name="AUDIT_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">        
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
        <marker>APPEND_SYSLOG</marker>
    </evaluator>
    <file>${USER_HOME}/mw_syslog.log</file>        
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="AUDIT_FILE" />
</root>


    12:07:01,515 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/JavaProjects/LogbackWeb/target/LogbackWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
    12:07:02,013 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
    12:07:02,134 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
    12:07:02,176 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [AUDIT_FILE]
    12:07:02,286 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@43:76 - no applicable action for [evaluator], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][evaluator]]
    12:07:02,286 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@44:21 - no applicable action for [marker], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][evaluator][marker]]
    12:07:02,310 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    12:07:02,828 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[AUDIT_FILE] - File property is set to [c:/temp/mw_syslog.log]
    12:07:02,836 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
    12:07:02,836 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [AUDIT_FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
    12:07:02,842 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
    12:07:02,855 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@3ad1a015 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In SMTPAppender the evaluator is used for triggering. In FileAppender, you need to encapsulate the evaluator within a filter, an [evaluator filter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#evalutatorFilter) to be precise. Here is an example:

```
<property name="USER_HOME" value="c:/temp" />

<appender name="AUDIT_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">        
    <!-- the filter element -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">   
      <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
        <marker>APPEND_SYSLOG</marker>
      </evaluator>
     <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
     <onMatch>NEUTRAL</onMatch>
   </filter>
    <file>${USER_HOME}/mw_syslog.log</file>        
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="AUDIT_FILE" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Ceki. That worked. Appreciate your help.By default all my logs will be logged in server.log and only the onces marked are being logged into this file specified in the FileAppender.

Comment: N.B. the `OnMarkerEvaluator` is broken in 1.1.7 - you'll get the error `Unexpected aggregationType AS_BASIC_PROPERTY_COLLECTION`.